# Extra PBKDF2 characters in SHA-512 output

Tags: hash, php, sha, sha2

I was using hash_pbkdf2 earlier today when I noticed something strange.

The normal way to generate a hash is to output the entire string like the code below which outputs a 128 character string (128 chars, 4 bit each, 512bit total):
`echo hash_pbkdf2("sha512", "123456", "test", 30000, 0);`
`c7b35be6c57b716fe4beb1ca33341ea32cb0de817636c115244db9c57cea1120828ea2b9f19805b24667c876d7b0e5ec4a3b05b3b793845ece2404106d781cda`

However I made a minor error which I noticed output a whole heap of extra data:
`echo hash_pbkdf2("sha512", "123456", "test", 30000, 512);`
`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`

What are the extra hex output by this bad code, I was under the impression that SHA-512 could only output a maximum of 512bits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [function definition](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-pbkdf2.php), you specified a bit length of 512. By default (`raw_output = False`) the extra bits come from the derived key.